# Android scrollview remove blue light

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

When you scroll on Android using scrollview, it generates a blue light the direction you are scrolling in. How would I remove the blue light?

My manifest:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/sobreScrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
android:scrollingCache="false" 
android:fadingEdge="none"
android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"  
    >    

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentSobre"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Java source code:

```
package com.my.app.section;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet; 
import com.my.app.BaseSection; 
import com.my.app.R;

public class SobreSection extends BaseSection {

public SobreSection(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public SobreSection(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SobreSection(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onFinishInflate();

    findViewById(R.id.sobreScrollView).setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
    findViewById(R.id.sobreScrollView).setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

}
  }
```

Comment: please describe your problem more accurate, do you want the blue overlay, or don't you want it?

Comment: I do not want the blue light when I roll by the end of scrollview

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Try adding this to your ScrollView in your layout.xml:

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

or add this to your code:

```
findViewById(R.id.sobreScrollView).setOverScrollMode(ScrollView.OVER_SCROLL_NEV‌​ER);
```

Comment: return Multiple markers at this line
 - OVER_SCROLL_NEVER cannot be resolved or is not a field
 - View cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Oops, sry it is inside the class ScrollView so it's: `ScrollView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER` :)

Comment: This (at least the XML version) works for `viewPager`'s as well!

Answer (score 11):

Add this extra line to your `ScrollView` definition:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sobreScrollView"
    ...
    android:overScrollMode="never">
```

Comment: return error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'overScrollMode' in package 'android'

Comment: It was added in API level 9. So you'll need to use a later SDK (9 or above) than the one you're currently using.