# Disable ScrollView bounce NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

Looking for a way to disable the ScrollView bounce or overflow that happens when scrolling reaches the top or bottom of the scroll view.

here how to set the settings in android. 
[Android scrollview remove blue light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200046/android-scrollview-remove-blue-light)

Comment: I figured it out for ios
if (app.ios) {
 scrollView.ios.bounces = false;
}


with `scrollView` being an instance of the scrollView you want to disable the bounce on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that might do the trick for you:

```
if (this.content.ios instanceof UIScrollView) {
        this.content.ios.alwaysBounceVertical = false;
 }
```

Of course you need to get an instance of the `<ScrollView>` component from NativeScript and then the native iOS instance.

Comment: How to do that in normal javascript (not microsoft script)?

Answer (score 1):

I have a small utility library that has this function and some other handy functions baked into it.

https://github.com/TheOriginalJosh/nativescript-swiss-army-knife

```
import {SwissArmyKnife} from 'nativescript-swiss-army-knife/nativescript-swiss-army-knife';

...

let scrollView = page.getViewById('myScrollView');

SwissArmyKnife.disableScrollBounce(scrollView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it on iOS and Android.

```
let scrollView = page.getViewById('myScrollView');
if (app.android) {
    scrollView.android.setOverScrollMode(2);
}
else if (app.ios) {
    scrollView.ios.bounces = false;
}
```